# Start Tweet From a Mac App

Tags: cocoa, macos, twitter

I'm writing a mac app and I'd like it to pass a message to a twitter client like Twitter or Twitterific.

Does anyone know how to do this?

In Twitter.app's Info.plist they declare a CFBundleTypeExtensions which looks promising because I can drag a snippet of text onto the Twitter.app icon and it will initialize a tweet.

However I tried doing this in code with:

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openFile:@"tweet tweet" withApplication:@"Twitter"];
```

But that just cuases this to be printed in the console:

```
LSOpenFromURLSpec() returned -43 for application Twitter path tweet tweet.
```

Twitterific does not define CFBundleTypeExtensions, so even if I can get this working for Twitter it won't work for Twitterific.

Does anyone know if this is documented anywhere? I've tried to find it in FAQs and things but haven't been able to yet.

Answer (score 1):

As the part `openFile:` suggests you pass a filename, not a generic string. So you might simply be able to dump your string into a temporary file and pass that filename. However, I don't know what file format Twitter expects and what it's doing with it.

Answer (score 0):

After some more digging I found this: http://twitterrific.com/ipad/poweruser

Funny enough the url works for Twitter.app but not Twitterific...

```
twitter://post?message=escapedString
```

I sent the Icon Factory a mail about this, hopefully I'm just missing something.